# Doctrine ORM: Multiple Navigational Properties to the same entity with composite primary key

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities `EntA` & `EntB` defined as follows:

```
<?php

#[ORM\Entity]
class EntA {
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(length=10)]
    private string $id1;
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(length=100)]
    private string $id2;

    public function __construct(string $id1, string $id2) {
        $this->id1 = $id1;
        $this->id2 = $id2;
    }
}

#[ORM\Entity]
class EntB {
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(length=50)]
    private string $id;
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: EntA::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "ref_id", referencedColumnName="id1")]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "ref_id2", referencedColumnName="id2")]
    private ?EntA $ref1 = null;
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: EntA::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "ref_id", referencedColumnName="id1")]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "ref_id2", referencedColumnName="id2")]
    private ?EntA $ref2 = null;
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: EntA::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "ref_id", referencedColumnName="id1")]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "ref_id3", referencedColumnName="id2", nullable=true)]
    private ?EntA $ref3 = null;

    public function __construct(EntA $ref1, EntA $ref2, ?EntA $ref3 = null) {
        $this->id = random_str();
        $this->ref1 = $ref1;
        $this->ref2 = $ref2;
        $this->ref3 = $ref3;
    }
}
```

Here's an hypothetical situation:

```
$ent_a_1 = new EntA("ABC", "123");
$entityManager->persist($ent_a_1);
$ent_a_2 = new EntA("ABC", "234");
$entityManager->persist($ent_a_2);

$ent_b = new EntB($ref_a_1, $ref_a_2);
$entityManager->persist($ent_b);

$entityManager->flush();
```

The design is to ensure that all reference to `EntA` from `EntB` all belong under the same parent and by parent, I mean `EntA::$id1`.

Whenever I instantiate `EntB` and set `EntB::$ref3` to null, doctrine sets the column `ref_id` in the `EntB` table to null thereby making the other `EntA` references to be orphans. even though columns `ref_id1`, `ref_id2` have their values intact while column `ref_id3` is null as expected.

The expected behaviour is as follows:

```
EntA Table
id1: ABC, id2: 123
id1: ABC, id2: 234 

EntB Table
id: aystetx, ref_id: ABC, ref_id1: 123, ref_id2: 234, ref_id3: null
```

What happens is as follows:

```
EntA Table
id1: ABC, id2: 123
id1: ABC, id2: 234 

EntB Table
id: aystetx, ref_id: null, ref_id1: 123, ref_id2: 234, ref_id3: null
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is this a bug in doctrine ORM?